# Initializing a queue in Python

Tags: python

I have initialized my queue in a constructor, like this:

```
class PingSweeper():

    def __init__(self,Networks,pending):
        self.Networks = ['192.168.1.0/28']
        self.pending  = queues.Queue()
```

When I create a PingSweeper object, it expects Networks and Pending to be passed in as parameters.  Here is how I am creating the PingSweeper object:

```
ping = PingSweeper('0.0.0.0',pending)
```

The first variable is Networks, which is an array, so I am passing '0.0.0.0', pending is a queue and I don't know what to pass for pending and it is telling me pending is not defined.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *The first variable is Networks, which is an array* - Then why are you passing a string? And you aren't doing anything with the parameters that you pass into the constructor

Comment: did you assign anything to `pending` when you are calling `PingSweeper`? That is your first problem. Second problem is in your `__init__` you are not even using the `pending` value you are passing to your `__init__` because you are just assigning `self.pending = queues.Queue()`. Furthermore, you are passing a string as your networks instead of what you said should be a list.

Answer (score 0):

Three problems

1. `Networks` should be an array, you are passing it in as a string
2. You never use the parameters of your constructor
3. If you are getting "pending is not defined" at `ping = PingSweeper('0.0.0.0',pending)`, that means you haven't defined a variable for `pending` within that scope

Here is a small example of the proper structure. Also python variables should be lowercased, like `networks`

```
import queue

class PingSweeper():
    def __init__(self, networks, pending):
        self.networks = networks
        self.pending = pending

scan_networks = ['192.168.1.0/28']
ping = PingSweeper(scan_networks, queue.Queue())

for net in ping.networks:
    print("Ping:", net)

ping.pending.put('0.0.0.0')
ping.pending.put('127.0.0.0')

while not ping.pending.empty():
    print("Scanning:", ping.pending.get())
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking to set default value for Networks and pending parameters:

```
import Queue

class PingSweeper():
    def __init__(self, Networks=['192.168.1.0/28'], pending=Queue.Queue()):
        self.Networks = Networks
        self.pending = pending
        print self.Networks
        print self.pending

ping = PingSweeper('0.0.0.0')
ping.pending.put('192.168.1.1')
ping.pending.put('192.168.1.2')
print ping.pending.get()
```